# memory leaks using NIntegrate on parallel kernel

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, parallelization, memory

**Bug fixed in version 10.2.0**

---

I'm running a large computation in parallel and the memory usage of the parallel kernels is increasing with every iteration of the calculation. Neither `$HistoryLength=0`, `ClearSystemCache[]`, nor `CleanSlate[]` can solve the issue. I narrowed the problem down to using `NIntegrate` on the parallel kernel. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
    ClearMemory := Block[{},
        Unprotect[In, Out];
        Clear[In, Out];
        Protect[In, Out];
        ClearSystemCache[];
       ];
    HGt[a_] := NIntegrate[t^a, {t, 0, 1}];
    calct[aa_] := Block[{$HistoryLength = 0, res},
        res = HGt[aa];
        ClearMemory;
        res
       ];
    CloseKernels[];
    LaunchKernels[1];
    ParallelEvaluate[$HistoryLength = 0];
DistributeDefinitions[calct];
ClearMemory;
jobs = Map[ParallelSubmit[Print[MemoryInUse[]]; calct[#]] &, Range[8]];
WaitAll[jobs]
```

As output I get:

```
(kernel 1) 17279624
(kernel 1) 19220336
(kernel 1) 19239064
(kernel 1) 19240160
(kernel 1) 19240896
(kernel 1) 19241632
(kernel 1) 19242368
(kernel 1) 21322872
{0.5, 0.333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.166667, 0.142857, 0.125, 0.111111}
```

If I use the same code with `NIntegrate` replaced by `NSum` the kernel doesn't leak memory:

```
(kernel 1) 17279624
(kernel 1) 17277056
(kernel 1) 17277392
(kernel 1) 17277392
(kernel 1) 17277392
(kernel 1) 17277392
(kernel 1) 17277392
(kernel 1) 17277392
```

Why is the parallel kernel leaking memory and how can I fix it?

Just closing and relaunching the kernels from time to time seems to be no solution, because I'm also experiencing [this problem](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366346).

I'm using Mathematica Version 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 9, 2014).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Fixed in version 10.2.

Answer (score 7):

(Reposting my comment as an answer, just to take the question off the unanswered list)

This is a bug and has been fixed in version 10.2. I am not aware of any workarounds that may be applicable in earlier versions.