# How to speed up the evaluation of a function with a large LeafCount but many repeated sub-functions for use in NIntegrate

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, memory, memoization

### General Context

Apparently, the [memory leak in `NIntegrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91816/nintegrate-has-memory-leak) is [unavoidable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88517/29734) pre-MMA-10.2. I have some (two-dimensional) numerical integration to do on a complicated function (`LeafCount[g]` is approximately 70 million or so) that is a function of a handful of parameters. Specifically, there is a function `g[kx_, ky_, x_, y_, params__]` for which I run

```
ParallelTable[
  NIntegrate[
    g[kx, ky, x, y, params]
    , {kx, 0, <large number>}
    , {ky, 0, <large number>}
  ]
  , {x, 0, 10, 0.2}
  , {y, 0, 10, 0.2}
]
```

where `<large number>` is large enough to guarantee reasonable convergence for the integral (the upper limit is actually infinite, and the function goes to zero at a rate of approximately `1/k^3`). Run on 8 kernels for a single choice of `params`, *every single one of these integrals* typically runs about 100 seconds, and the entire evaluation of the `Table` ends up eating up about 50 GB (of a total 64 GB) of RAM, and since `NIntegrate` doesn't release this memory, the computer crashes once the integration for the second set of parameters starts up. Of course, I have many different parameter sets I'd like to run, so I'd like this to be automated to run over a weekend or something rather than have to `Quit[]` and run for a different set of parameters by hand. Some day, perhaps, I'll get access to 10.2, but for now I have to look for work-arounds.

### Specific Context of This Question

Due to this, I am trying my best to cut down on how much work `NIntegrate` has to do in order to bring down the RAM usage. I am currently simplifying the function "by hand" as much as possible, but I hit on one possible idea that might help out.

The idea is that within the function `g`, there are repeated uses of another function `f` that has a somewhat large `LeafCount` on its own (maybe 2000 or so), and the repeated use of `f` inside `g` is part of the reason `g` has such a large `LeafCount` when I substitute `f` into `g`. My thought was to leave `f` in (rather than substitute in the corresponding expression involving `kx`, `ky`, `x`, `y`, and `params`) and somehow make a *single* call to `f` when evaluating `g` at a particular value in order to speed things up. One thought I had was to use memoization, as in the example below. Another possibility is to define `g` with a `Symbol` `h` in place of `f[vars__]`, and define

```
g1[vars__] := Block[{h = f[vars]}, g[vars]];
```

### Questions

**(1) What is the best way to go about speeding up the evaluation of a function `g` with a large `LeafCount` due to a function `f` with large `LeafCount` appearing in the definition of `g` multiple times?**

**(2) What is the best way to accomplish (1) when the function `g` is to be `NIntegrate`d?**

I suspect that the answer to this second question depends a lot on the actual structure of both `f` and `g`. Given `LeafCount` of `g` is approximately 70 million, I'm willing to bet you don't want to see the actual definitions, so the best I can say is that there are a lot of nested square roots (my test function below does not).

Note that I have an answer below, but I welcome more answers, since this was the first thing that I hit upon, and it may not work for my actual function.

### Minimal Examples, Possible Solutions, and Exploration

Let's take as our sample function

```
g[x_] = Nest[f[x] + 1./# &, f[x], 500];
```

which is a continued fraction of depth-500 with `f[x]` appearing at every level. For the purposes of having a function `f` that takes a little bit of time to compute, let's use

```
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}];
```

Now, we note the following. (All timings were done with MMA 10.0.2.0 on a MacBook Air running OSX 10.10.5.)

#### Evaluation of `g`

There is a factor of ~50 speed-up for a memo-ized version of `f` over `f` defined using either `Set` (even more for `SetDelayed`):

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}];
First@AbsoluteTiming@g[5.]
(* 0.195406 *)

Clear[f]
f[x_] := Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@g[5.]
(* 0.285290 *)

Clear[f]
f[x_] := f[x] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}];
First@AbsoluteTiming@g[5.]
(* 0.004211 *)
```

The `Block` solution gives a 6x speed-up over the `Set` version:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
g[x_] = Nest[h + 1./# &, h, 500];
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}];
g1[x_] := Block[{h = f[x]}, g[x]]
First@AbsoluteTiming@g1[5.]
(* 0.040647 *)
```

#### Plotting `g`

There is a factor of ~70 speed for the memo-ized version of `f`:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}]
(* 46.138497 *)

Clear[f]
f[x_] := f[x] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}]
Length@DownValues@f
(* 0.652008 *)
(* 161 *)
```

`f[x]` was evaluated 161 times.

The `Block` solution gives a factor of 6 speed-up over the non-memoized version:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
g[x_] = Nest[h + 1./# &, h, 500];
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 1, 100}];
g1[x_] := Block[{h = f[x]}, g[x]]
First@AbsoluteTiming@Plot[g1[x], {x, 0, 5}]
(* 5.879858 *)
```

#### `NIntegrate` `g`

The memo-ized version doesn't help much at all, and I think that is because `NIntegrate` constructs the symbolic function `g` completely before it goes through the numerical integration process; that is, `f[x]` gets plugged into `g[x]` before the integration occurs, which defeats the whole purpose:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
(* 0.824581 *)

Clear[f]
f[x_] := f[x] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
{First@#, Length@#}& @ DownValues@f
(* 0.512885 *)
(* {HoldPattern[f[5.]] :> 1.59104, 3} *)
```

`DownValues` of `f` includes only `f[5.]`, which seems to verify my hypothesis.

The `Block` version doesn't help, again probably because it all gets plugged in before `NIntegrate` occurs:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
g[x_] = Nest[h + 1./# &, h, 500];
f[x_] = Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}];
g1[x_] := Block[{h = f[x]}, g[x]]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g1[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
(* 0.531379 *)
```

Comment: By using `NIntegrate[...,Method->{Automatic,"SymbolicProcessing"->0}]` I could again gain a factor of ~2 speed up for the integration. Maybe that also helps a little

Comment: @Lukas. It's worth a shot, although I think *some* symbolic processing is good, as shown by the answer below: it seems like it might be a balancing act.

Comment: That's definitely true. I'm not experienced enough to find that balancing, though. But I am very curious if someone will... Or if someone has a completely different way to solve it

Answer (score 5):

### Compile `f` and use a memo-ized version of it

Since it seems like `NIntegrate` decides to symbolically evaluate its argument first, I thought I'd force it not to by compiling the function `f`. This seems to make a significant difference:

```
Clear[f, f1, g]
g[x_] = Nest[f[x] + 1./# &, f[x], 500];
f1 = Compile[{x}, Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]];
f[x_?NumericQ] := f1[x]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
(* 0.049145 *)
```

This is a factor of 10 speed-up over the versions in the question. We can also memo-ize `f`, leading to slightly more speed-up, and we can in the mean-time verify that the `DownValues` actually get assigned:

```
Clear[f, f1, g]
g[x_] = Nest[f[x] + 1./# &, f[x], 500];
f1 = Compile[{x}, Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]];
f[x_?NumericQ] := f[x] = f1[x]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
Length@DownValues@f
(* 0.040601 *)
(* 35 *)
```

Now, I expect that memoizing `f` in this way is a bad idea, due to `NIntegrate` running many times over for different parameter sets, and so a huge number of `DownValues` will eventually be attached to `f`, possible leading to slow-down. It may be reasonable to [`Block` off the memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/29734) to a single call to `NIntegrate`.

**Interestingly,**

the memoized version doesn't provide extra speed-up once called, even if the integration is exactly the same:

```
g[x_] = Nest[f[x] + 1./# &, f[x], 500];
f1 = Compile[{x}, Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}]];
f[x_?NumericQ] := f[x] = f1[x]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
(* 0.041787 *)
(* 0.040696 *)
```

I definitely don't understand why this doesn't make a difference, since the `x`-values chosen are definitely the same, and so the second `NIntegrate` calls `g` on these values, and so uses `f` evaluated at these values, which it has already done.

On the other hand, if we `Compile` `g` instead and memoize, the first integration takes a long time, but after that it is very quick:

```
ClearAll[g, g1, g2]
g2[x_] = Nest[Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}] + 1./# &, Sum[1/100 Erfc[-(x^2/k)], {k, 100}], 500];
g1 = Compile[{x}, g2[x]];
g[x_?NumericQ] := g[x] = g1[x];
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
First@AbsoluteTiming@NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 5.}]
(* 3.471362 *)
(* 0.003585 *)
```

I suspect that the integral takes so much longer because `NIntegrate` can't do any examinations of the symbolic structure of `g` at the beginning and so can't decide how to cleverly evaluate the integral. In any case, this would be useful if we could guarantee that `NIntegrate` would choose the same `x`-values on which to evaluate `g`. This is not the case in general, of course.